# Transforming a polygon to a linestring

Tags: python, polygon, line, convert

Is it possible to (trivially, via a tool in python) to convert a polygon to a linestring? if so, how? If not, why?

Comment: Which format is your polygon in to begin with?

Comment: WSG84 read from a shapefile

Comment: How are you reading it from a shapefile? Try editing your question and showing some code.

Comment: For example, if you are reading using `fiona` and `shapely` the linestring for a polygon is the `boundary` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest way I think is to use [boundary](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.boundary) method in Shapely lib. When using

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon
Polygon(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0]).boundary
```

it returns

```
LINESTRING (30.916671 55.61667, 31.166671 56.91667, 32.550004 57.350003,...)
```

In case **Multipolygon** it obviously returns Multilinestring:

```
multy = MultiPolygon([Point(0, 0).buffer(1.0), Point(1, 1).buffer(1.0)])
multyline = multy.boundary
print(multy)
print(multyline)

MULTIPOLYGON (((1 0, 0.9951847266721969 -0.09801714032956051, ...))((...)))
MULTILINESTRING ((1 0, 0.9951847266721969 -0.09801714032956051, ...)(...))
```

**QGIS way:**

Vector -> Geometry tools -> Polygons to lines